# Understanding rowwise() and c_across()

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

Hi there: Can anyone offer a layperson's explanation for why these two ways of trying to calculate an row average of scores work differently?
Thanks.

```
library(tidyverse)
var1<-rnorm(100)
var2<-rnorm(100)
var3<-rnorm(100)

df<-data.frame(var1, var2, var3)

#ADD IN A MISSING VALUE
df[1,1]<-NA

#I thought this would work
df %>% 
  select(starts_with('var')) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(avg=mean(., na.rm=T))
#This does work but I don't understand why
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(avg=
           mean(
             c_across(starts_with('var')), na.rm=T)
         )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `.` represents the entire dataset and not the grouped data.
- Moreover, `mean` doesn't work on dataframes. (see `mean(mtcars)`)

Since  `dplyr` 1.0.0 (or higher) you can use `cur_data()` to get data in the group but to use it in `mean` you need to change it to vector which can be done with `unlist` or `as.matrix`. So try :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  select(starts_with('var')) %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(avg=mean(unlist(cur_data()), na.rm=T))
```

Your second approach however, is the correct way to use `rowwise`.