# R random forest aggregate vs individual prediction

Tags: r, random-forest

Please consider this minimal reproducible example of a random forest regression estimate

```
library(randomForest)

# fix missing data
airquality <- na.roughfix(airquality)

set.seed(123)
#fit the random forest model
rf_fit <- randomForest(formula = Ozone ~ .,  data = airquality)

#define new observation
new <- data.frame(Solar.R=250, Wind=8, Temp=70, Month=5, Day=5)

set.seed(123)
#use predict all on new observation
rf_predict<-predict(rf_fit, newdata=new, predict.all = TRUE)

rf_predict$aggregate

library(tidyverse)

predict_mean <- rf_predict$individual %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  transmute(avg = mean(V1:V500))

predict_mean
```

I was expecting to get the same value by `rf_predict$aggregate` and `predict_mean`

Where and why am I wrong about this assumption?

My final objective is to get a confidence interval of the predicted value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your code needs to include a `c_across()` call for the calculation to be performed correctly:

The `?c_across` documentations tells us:

> c_across() is designed to work with rowwise() to make it easy to
> perform row-wise aggregations.

```
predict_mean <- rf_predict$individual %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  transmute(avg = mean(c_across(V1:V500)))

>predict_mean
[1] 30.5
```

[An answer to a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64282932/5456906), points out that `mean()` can't handle a data.frame. And in your code the data being provide to `mean()` is **a row-wise data frame with class rowwise_df**. `c_across` allows the data in the rows to be presented to `mean()` as vectors (I think).

Comment: thank you for pointing out what I must consider my "big blunder";
but on second thought I'm still a little bit confused by this...

`library(tidyverse)

t <- tibble(a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4)

# why this is working here
t %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  transmute(avg=mean(a:d))

t %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  transmute(avg=mean(c_across(a:d)))

# to be noted that with c_across 
# you can use the tidy select semantics everything(), which is a quite handy feature
t %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  transmute(avg=mean(c_across(cols = everything())))`

Comment: Interesting. I've added some explanation of how I understand the issue.

Comment: I guess `rowMeans()` is the appropriate base function to be used instead of `mean`;

`t %>% rowwise() %>%  transmute(avg=rowMeans(.))`

but still, remains (to me at least) the issue (my doubt!) why in my previous example this IS NOT failing:

`t %>% rowwise() %>%  transmute(avg=mean(c_across(a:d)))`